# Removing the background image

Tags: android

I set backgruound image as

```
android:background="@drawable/drag"
```

now I want to delete this image from activity

View configView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.detail_view, null);
how is it possible. I am using SDK version 14.

Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Clarify your question with detail code.

Comment: You can use This code: relative.setBackgroundcolor(null);

Comment: the layout I am accessing in the activity where the backround image set from the xml need to be removed.. Thanks..

Comment: @ sr.farzad this wont work I try it out..

Answer (score 2):

Try this if its Layout

> 1) RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout)
>   findViewById(R.id.widget29); relative.setBackground(null);

This is related for view

> 2) imgView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
android:background="@null"
```

or

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: He wants this from Activity(java)

Answer (score 0):

use view.setbackground(null) (API level >= 16), or view.setBackgroundDrawable(null) (for API level < 16) in your code, whenever u need to remove them programmatically.